# How to fix the look-controls when a-sky’s X rotated?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I need rotate X axis of `a-sky` in my task in a 360 image liked project, but when I rotated, the `look-controls` works weird. The reason may be that camera's axis need change, and how can I change that camera's axis ?

[look-controls works weird](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXGWQB)

```
<a-sky src="#skyTexture" rotation="30 0 0"></a-sky>
```

Comment: In short, how to let the `look-controls` works like without rotate the sky?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to change the basis axes of the camera space, the easiest way to do that is wrapping the camera with a rotated object:

```
    <a-entity rotation = "30 0 0">
        <a-camera look-controls>
        </a-camera>
    </a-entity>
```

But, be careful, if you do that, all the objects in the scene would have a slope.

Answer (score 0):

The controls are okay, You crooked the image, and the horizon is no longer a perfect circle around the camera, so Your perception feels off. If You rotate the camera, You will see the same image as if You didn't change anything.

---

I made a quick comparison of the rotations:[image]
Take a look what is the relation of the horizon on the image, and the (0,0,0) grid. You can't rotate the sky in x, or z, and expect the guy to be lower and the horizon to be normal.

---

If You want the user to be "higher", change the `a-sky` to a `a-sphere` and position it a bit lower than the camera, like i did here: https://codepen.io/gftruj/pen/Kqbxbx.

---

Craig.Li's anwser is correct if You want to rotate the camera, but its a bad idea to mess with the camera since the user should be the only one manipulating the camera ( what i think the initial intention of a-frame was ).